# popup for delete confirmation from actionlink

Tags: jquery, popup, actionlink

I want to create a **pop-up** for when click **delete** it will show the confirmation pop up..The popup will contains "**Yes**" & "**No**". If i click **Yes** it will delete the process. **No** means it will come out...

I tried many pop up's. but i cannot implement the logic...

**My Html Code:**

```
      <td>
        <h3>Delete the Job</h3><br />
        <% foreach(Models.Job job in Model.Jobs) { %>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Jobs", new { id = job.Id }, new { target = "_blank" })%> <br/>  
        <% } %>
      </td>
```

When I click **Delete link** it will load the pop up... Can anyone help me pls....

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some javascript especialy the confirm() fonction.

```
if (confirm("Do you realy want to delete ?"))
   deleteStuff();
else
   return false;
```

It will show an alert box with "ok" or "cancel".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <td>
    <h3>Delete the Job</h3><br />
    <% foreach(Dial4Jobz.Models.Job job in Model.Jobs) { %>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Jobs", new { onclick="ConfirmMessage("+ job.Id +")"}, new { target = "_blank" })%> <br/>  
    <% } %>
  </td>
```

JS

```
  function confirmMesage( id) {        
    if(confirm("Do you really want to delete ?")) {
        Delete(id);
    };
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is ConfirmMessage function put into jquery?

Comment: Yes, This is Javascript function